# Unable to access programs and documents using run command on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, run-dialog

Earlier I use to access all the programs like excel word etc by directly through run command and also use to search documents from run command only but all of a sudden it stopped working it gives the error as in following:

```
These files can not be opened
your internet security settings prevented one or more files from being opened.
```

Comment: check you default application for these files . is it happening for all applications or just ms office applications ?

Comment: See this page...http://windows7forums.com/windows-vista-support/49167-internet-security-settings-prevents-one-more-files-being-opened.html

Comment: Its happening for all applications and documents also adhering to the steps provided by Moab haven't given any positive results.

Comment: how about user privileges? are you a common user or an administrator?

Comment: do you use "execute" like me: winword, write, soffice, calc, notepad, firefox, explorer, iexplore, context, msnmsgr, mplayerc, mpc-hc, wmplayer, cmd...? did you try also ".COM" or paths with other kind of extensions (.DOC, .HTM, .TXT...)?

Answer (score 0):

Try that: http://forums.techarena.in/operating-systems/1382204.htm

23-12-2010
Elijah

Re: These files can not be opened
I got the solution for this problem and it has already worked for me: Try to create another user. After creating with the help of the administrator toggle to the newly created user. Now in that from the run menu run the command regedit. Now you move on to the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings. Under that select and perform the right click onto it and export it to the public folder or to the root directory. Then you should toggle back once again to the original user account. Remove the above keys and then run the exported .reg.

Answer (score 0):

Try that too: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/when-trying-to-search-in-windows-7-start-menu-get/17baf19c-cdd5-4a21-9daa-67e6abb9d566